# pdftools::pdf_text() error reading in file

Tags: r, pdftools

I am having an issue using R/Rstudio reading in a pdf file using the pdftools::pdf_text() function.

```
dat <- pdf_text("Summary Payroll Register BY ENTITY SM HLM ONLY 081321.pdf")
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
path[1]="Summary Payroll Register BY ENTITY SM HLM ONLY 081321.pdf": Access is denied
```

I do not get this issue reading a csv file:

```
dat <- read_csv('test.csv')
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  person = col_character(),
  age = col_double()
)
```

I believe this issue has to do with the fact I am using my company computer and my files are no longer being saved on my actual machine (Desktop or Documents folders) they are instead now being saved directly to the company network shared drive.

Any thoughts on a workaround?

Comment: Is your Rstudio project working out of that shared drive?